# How does MaterialUI do this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, material-ui, vuetify.js

If you look at their autocomplete component: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/

After you click a suggestion in the dropdown, the input box keeps focus... How do they do that? In every variation of this in my own vue app (not using material UI) I can't get the click event to stop an input from losing focus.

I have tried googling this for quite some time and there is no clear solution that I see. For example, people suggest mousedown/touchstart but that would break scrolling (via dragging the dropdown). MaterialUI obviously doesn't have this problem, and doesn't seem to be using mousedown.

I've tried analyzing the events using Chrome dev tools and I can only see a single click event, but with minified code it's difficult to tell what's going on.

Vuetify also does this: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VAutocomplete/VAutocomplete.ts

I did find this too which is helpful, if anyone comes across this issue https://codepen.io/Pineapple/pen/MWBVqGW

**Edit** Here's what Im doing:

```html
  <app-input-autocomplete 
    @autocomplete-select="onSelect"
    @autocomplete-close="onClose"
    :open="open">
    <template #default="{ result }">
      <div class="input-autocomplete-address">
        {{ result.address }}
      </div>
    </template>
  </app-input-autocomplete>
```

and then in `app-input-autocomplete`:

```html
<template>
  <app-input
    @focus="onFocus"
    @blur="onBlur"
    v-bind="$attrs">
    <template #underInput>
      <div ref="dropdown" v-show="open" class="input-autocomplete-dropdown">
        <div class="input-autocomplete-results">
          <div v-for="result in results" :key="result.id" @click="onClick(result)" class="input-autocomplete-result">
            <slot :result="result" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </app-input>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, toRef } from 'vue';
import AppInput from '@/components/AppInput.vue';
import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core';

export default {
  components: {
    AppInput,
  },
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    results: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => ([]),
    },
  },
  emits: ['autocomplete-close', 'autocomplete-select'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const dropdown = ref(null);

    const open = toRef(props, 'open');

    const focused = ref(false);

    onClickOutside(dropdown, () => {
      if (!focused.value && open.value) {
        emit('autocomplete-close');
      }
    });

    return {
      dropdown,
      focused,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFocus() {
      this.focused = true;
    },
    onBlur() {
      this.focused = false;
    },
    onClick(result) {
      this.$emit('autocomplete-select', result);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have added my source for vue autocomplete component I am manually building

Comment: based on the code in github, https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-base/src/AutocompleteUnstyled/useAutocomplete.js#L885  it appears that they are providing a custom event to handle when `blur` happens.  I don't have time to do a deep dive right this moment, but I hope this points you in the right direction.  It looks like they are calling this event for `onBlur()`, and then using flags from other events to determine when they can keep the focus alive.

Comment: and here at https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-base/src/AutocompleteUnstyled/useAutocomplete.js#L963 they are using `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following, thanks to @Claies for the idea to look, and also this link:

https://codepen.io/Pineapple/pen/MWBVqGW

1. `event.preventDefault` on `mousedown`
2. @click on result behaves like normal (close input)
3. @click/@focus on input set `open = true`
4. @blur sets open = false